# Flutter - CheckboxListTile - Border color white

Tags: flutter, dart

I don't have any idea how to change the color of checkbox border and move the text closer. Below is my code and image of I want to achieve.

Thanks!

[image]

```
CheckboxListTile(
                  title: const Text('Remember Me'),
                  value: _isSelected,
                  onChanged: (bool value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _isSelected = value;
                    });
                  },
                  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                ),
```

Comment: you have no control over those properties when using `CheckboxListTile`

Answer (score 13):

Try this solution:

```
Theme(
    data: ThemeData(unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.white),
    child: CheckboxListTile(....),
    )
```

Comment: This works but then the text of the list tile changes.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `side` property to change the checkbox's color and width when unselected.

```
CheckboxListTile(
    side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

these two property check color and active color helps you to change the color of check box ..
for moving closer the text .You can use Container or Row :
you can use row with main axis alignment.

Answer (score 1):

If someone tries to change the border of the Checkbox list tile, not the checkbox itself.

```
CheckboxListTile(
  title: const Text('text'),
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0), // Optionally
    side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.pink),
  ),
  value: true,
  onChanged: (_) {},
)
```

Makes it look like that.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can override your Theme

```
Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
    checkboxTheme: Theme.of(context).checkboxTheme.copyWith(
          fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
            (_) => !isDisabled
                ? Colors.white
                : Theme.of(context).disabledColor,
          ),
        ),
  ),
  child: CheckboxListTile(
    onChanged: onChanged,
    ...
    enabled: !isDisabled,
    dense: true,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Checkbox inside a Row

```
Row(children:[Checkbox(...), Text(...)]);
```